# Loading a link directly to div location

Tags: html

I am looking on a way to jump in directly to one of the div which is working once I click.
I would like it to load automatically to the div and not by clicking anything.

```
<div id="Number">
    <label>
        <p style="font-size:16px; color: black; background-color: #ffff42">My Cases</p>
    </label>
</div>
<iframe src="https://example.com/sr/" name="target-iframe"></iframe>
<a href="https://example.emc.com/sr/#Number" target="target-iframe" onclick="frames['target-iframe'].document.getElementById('Number')
                .scrollIntoView();return false">Click</a>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Well, you need some event to trigger the action. This does not have to be a click event, anything else will do as well. Hovering over the diff, right upon loading of the page itself or even a time based event (so after 5 seconds, or even _now_). Attach a handler to the event you decide to go for and load the content. And it does make sense to use a separate javascript file instead of relying on the old style in-html event handlers like `onClick="..."`...

Comment: thanks, but can you help with with the required lines\code? I am pretty new to this.

Comment: That is pretty broad a question. I suggest you look for a few basic `jquery` examples on google, they will show you how to execute an action on the client side right upon loading the html page. It is not really complex and offers you all flexibility you want.

Answer (score 0):

could you try focus on the DIV, that may or may not work:

give the Div a unique id (In your case Number)

```
<body onload="location.hash = 'Number';">
<div class="Number" id="Number">content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: it's good option but still, I need to press on "content" to make it work. Any way to make it happen automatically?

Comment: It's always a bad idea to have a class that is identical to an ID. It is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to automatically load the value present in div tag into iframe,just try to separate into two html file and put in the same directory.
for example,consider two html files one.html and ex.html.one.html

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
 <label>
        <p style="font-size:16px; color: black; background-color: #ffff42">My Cases</p>
    </label>
</div>         
</body>
</html>
```

ex.html is

```
 <html>
     <body>
             <iframe src="one.html" name="target-iframe">
             </iframe>         
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I tried it... still have to press on "click" to make it happen. I am looking for a way it will happen automaticlly